# Why the Spring-boot application requires CommandLineRunner to insert new records?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am learning Spring-Boot by following this tutorial:
[Spring Rest Hello World](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-rest-hello-world-example/)

In the last step (i.e. step 6), the Spring-boot application adds 3 Book entities to the H2 memory database using the following code snippet:

```
// init bean to insert 3 books into h2 database.
@Bean
CommandLineRunner initDatabase(BookRepository repository) {
    return args -> {
        repository.save(new Book("A Guide to the Bodhisattva Way of Life", "Santideva", new BigDecimal("15.41")));
        repository.save(new Book("The Life-Changing Magic of Tidying Up", "Marie Kondo", new BigDecimal("9.69")));
        repository.save(new Book("Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code", "Martin Fowler", new BigDecimal("47.99")));
    };
}
```

I just don't understand why the tutorial requires CommandLineRunner in order to insert the 3 Book record.

Can someone help me out on this?

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? Why insert 3 books? Why use command line runner to do it? What a command line runner is? Have you read https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-command-line-runner?

Comment: I don't understand why the tutorial needs to create CommandLineRunner to insert records. Is there any specific reason to do this? Can we just place the logic in the main method, right after "SpringApplication.run(StartBookApplication.class, args);"?

Comment: Sure, you could. But you would then have to lookup the context to get a referece to the BookRepository, instead of using dependency injection, which is what Spring is about.

Comment: So can I say it this way? The purpose for CommandLineRunner is to add custom logic when the Spring-boot application starts?

Comment: **has started**. First sentence from the documentation that I linked to in my first comment: *If you need to run some specific code once the SpringApplication has started, you can implement the ApplicationRunner or CommandLineRunner interfaces*. Read te documentation. You'll learn a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses the previously defined `BookRepository` in order to insert three `Book` records. This allows for verifying that the service works as expected.

Without it, testing the service with `curl` in Step 7 would not return a result. Though the author could have organized the tests such that the updates are executed first.

It is not a crucial step in developing services, but it shows that there is an easy way to interact with Spring components.